# Grid doesn't expand horizontally

Tags: c++, qt

I'm struggling in understand why the second grid doesn't expand horizontally:

Posting the image/gif as link to don't pollute the thread.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwwgx.png

https://i.imgur.com/1sokJVO.gif

Source file of the `ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>QtWidgetsApplication1Class</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="QtWidgetsApplication1Class">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>860</width>
    <height>701</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>QtWidgetsApplication1</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QMainWindow {
border-image: url(:/QtWidgetsApplication1/C:/MEGAsync/sw22.png);
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>64</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">#widget {
    background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 120);
}</string>
        </property>
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_5">
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeType">
            <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>40</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item row="3" column="0" alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignVCenter">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_11">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>42</width>
             <height>38</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">QPushButton:enabled {
    border-image: url(:/QtWidgetsApplication1/files/ddofus.png);
    background-color: red;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: beige;
    font: bold 14px;
    padding: 0px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(170, 255, 0);
    border-style: inset;
}

QPushButton:released {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    border-style: inset;
}

QPushButton:hover:!pressed {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="2" column="0">
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer_10">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeType">
            <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item row="4" column="0">
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer_11">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>40</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="0">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_10">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>42</width>
             <height>38</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">QPushButton:enabled {
    border-image: url(:/QtWidgetsApplication1/files/sw.jpg);
    background-color: red;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: beige;
    font: bold 14px;
    padding: 0px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(170, 255, 0);
    border-style: inset;
}

QPushButton:released {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    border-style: inset;
}

QPushButton:hover:!pressed {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
      <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
       <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget_4">
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>16777215</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="currentIndex">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="page_13">
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_9">
          <item row="2" column="0">
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_9">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeType">
             <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>40</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item row="6" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">font: 16px;
color: white;</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Password</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="4" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>32</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QLineEdit:enabled {
    /*border-image: url(:/file/C:/MEGAsync/sw3.png);*/
   
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 130);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-origin: content; /* the left margin of background image will 'obey' the padding-left defined up above (10px) */

    color : white;   /* TEXT COLOR */

    border-radius: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-left: 5px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    /* border-width: 5px; */
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 180);

    padding: 0 px 0 px; /* top - right - bottom - left */

}

QLineEdit:hover {
    /*border-image: url(:/file/C:/MEGAsync/sw3.png);*/
   
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 160);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-origin: content; /* the left margin of background image will 'obey' the padding-left defined up above (10px) */

    color : white;   /* TEXT COLOR */

    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 210);

    padding: 0 px 0 px; /* top - right - bottom - left */

}</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>100</width>
              <height>100</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">border-image: url(:/QtWidgetsApplication1/files/download1.png);</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string/>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="8" column="0">
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_12">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeType">
             <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>10</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item row="11" column="0">
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>32</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QPushButton:enabled {
    background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);
    
    color: white;  /* TEXT COLOR */

    border-style: none;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;    
    border-color: rgb(212, 141, 0);

    font: 19px;  /* font: bold 14px; */
    padding: 0px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(170, 255, 0);
    border-style: inset;
}

QPushButton:released {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    border-style: inset;
}

QPushButton:hover:!pressed {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Login</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="9" column="0">
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">font: 16px;
color: white;</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Remember-me</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="5" column="0">
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeType">
             <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>10</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item row="7" column="0">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>32</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QLineEdit:enabled {
    /*border-image: url(:/file/C:/MEGAsync/sw3.png);*/
   
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 130);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-origin: content; /* the left margin of background image will 'obey' the padding-left defined up above (10px) */

    color : white;   /* TEXT COLOR */

    border-radius: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-left: 5px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    /* border-width: 5px; */
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 180);

    padding: 0 px 0 px; /* top - right - bottom - left */

}

QLineEdit:hover {
    /*border-image: url(:/file/C:/MEGAsync/sw3.png);*/
   
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 160);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-origin: content; /* the left margin of background image will 'obey' the padding-left defined up above (10px) */

    color : white;   /* TEXT COLOR */

    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 210);

    padding: 0 px 0 px; /* top - right - bottom - left */

}</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="3" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">font: 16px;
color: white;</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Email</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="0">
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>136</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item row="12" column="0">
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_4">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeType">
             <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>80</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item row="10" column="0">
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_8">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeType">
             <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="page_14"/>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="2">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
      <item row="0" column="4">
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer_7">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="4">
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer_6">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="5">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="4">
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer_5">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="4">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_6">
        <item row="0" column="1">
         <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_5">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeType">
           <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>40</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="2">
         <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget_3">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>100</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>300</width>
            <height>16777215</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="page_11">
           <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_8">
            <item row="0" column="0">
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
              <property name="text">
               <string>test2</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="page_12"/>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget_2">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>200</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="page_9">
           <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_7">
            <item row="0" column="0">
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
              <property name="text">
               <string>test1</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="page_10"/>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="4">
       <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>300</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">#stackedWidget {
border-image: url(:/QtWidgetsApplication1/C:/MEGAsync/256.png);
}</string>
        </property>
        <property name="currentIndex">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="page_7">
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout"/>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="page_8">
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_12">
          <item row="0" column="0">
           <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_11">
            <item row="0" column="0" alignment="Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTop">
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
              <property name="text">
               <string>xx</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Minimum</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources>
  <include location="QtWidgetsApplication1.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

All grids where created as `Grid Layout`, its something inside of the grid at the right side which is blocking the second grid to expand horizontally, but I cant understand what.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @G.M. i post the source of the ui file, open it into Qt Designer and this is the example